# Integral partition for $f(x)=x^2$ on $[1,3]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum, partitions-for-integration

I'm struggling with this question:

- If we have $f(x) = x^2 $ and $P_n $ which partitions $[1,3]$ into $n$ sub-intervals, each equal in length, how can I write the formulas for $L(f,P_n)$ and $U(f,P_n)$ in terms of $n$?
- Do they converge to the same limit as $n$ goes to infinity?
- How large does $n$ need to be so that $U(f,P_n)$ is within $0.01$ of $\int_1^3 \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ ?

Comment: ...and you did **what** so far? Did you observe $\;x^2\;$ is monotone ascending for $\;x>0\;$ ? This makes the writing of $\;L, U\;$ almost trivial...

Comment: There is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050924/show-that-a-function-is-integrable-by-definition/2050964#2050964). Have a look and work similarly.

Answer (score 2):

The partition $P_n$ consists of the intervals $\left\{ \left[1+\frac{k-1}{n/2},1+\frac{k}{n/2} \right] \right\}_{k=1}^n$

Since $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing we have $$L(f,P_n)=\sum_{k=1}^nm_k \frac{2}{n}=\sum_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac{k-1}{n/2} \right)^2 \frac{2}{n}, \\U(f,P_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n M_k \frac{2}{n}=\sum_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac{k}{n/2} \right)^2 \frac{2}{n}.$$

This should help you a little.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Would you mind explaining this a bit more? How did you get that interval [1 + ..., 1 + ... ] ?

Comment: @user114425 since you want to divide the interval $[1,3]$ - of length 2 into $n$ subintervals, each must have length $2/n$.